# Is there any equivalent property to ButtonTintList in Xamarin.Forms Android API level 19

Tags: android, xamarin.forms

In API level 28 I am using BackgroundTintList property,but when using it in Anroid API level 19, getting exception.

Exception Detail:
Java.Lang.NoSuchMethodError: no method with name='setButtonTintList' signature='(Landroid/content/res/ColorStateList;)V' in class Landroid/widget/CompoundButton;

Is there any equivalent property to ButtonTintList in Xamarin.Forms Android API level 19

Comment: How do you use this property? Could you provide the code? Which one do you want to use `ButtonTintList` or BackgroundTintList`?

Comment: I use this property to save the ColorStateList.I want to use ButtonTintList.Which in working in API 28 but not in API 19.
Is any other property can be used which works as ButtonTintList?

Answer (score 0):

You could use `setColorFilter` instead. It is used to specify a color and Porter-Duff mode to be the color filter for this drawable. This method was deprecated in API level 29.

`setColorFilter`:https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/Drawable#setColorFilter(int,%20android.graphics.PorterDuff.Mode)